# Vue.js AJAX call inside Modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, vue.js, bootstrap-modal, axios

I am trying to have a modal pop up with details of a credit card. The details come from an AJAX request. For some reason the root Vue instance is updating but the component instance is not. This is what I currently have -

HTML:

```
<!-- View Card Details Modal -->
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="ccdetails" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">View Card Details</h4>
      </div>
      <card-details cardid="{{$cc->card_id}}" :message="getCCDetails('{{$cc->card_id}}')"></card-details>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button> -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Vue JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Vue.component('card-details', {
  template: '<div class="modal-body">@{{message}}</div>',
  // data is technically a function, so Vue won't
  // complain, but we return the same object
  // reference for each component instance
 props: ['message', 'cardid']
}),
new Vue({
  el: '#ccdetails',
  data: {
    cardid: '',
    message: ''
  },
  methods: {
        getCCDetails: function (id) {
            console.log(id)
            console.log('calling function')
             axios.get('/card/'.concat(id))
                  .then(function (response) {
                    this.message = JSON.stringify(response.data)
                  }.bind(this))
                  .catch(function (error) {
                    return this.message = 'Sorry there was an error'
                  }.bind(this));
        }
  }
})
</script>
```

For the output, Root instance has `cardid = undefined` and `message = the output` I want. My cardDetails instance has the `cardid` value correct but `message = undefined`.

Comment: Which version of Vue is it? And, what exactly is $cc variable?

Comment: It is a little confusing. You'll need to add an example for your $cc. in a comment below you claimed there can be multiple $cc - therefore I'd say you are not looping anywhere. Did you ensure that $cc->card_id is not null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try events

Add event listener in component:

```
Vue.component('card-details', {
        template: '<div class="modal-body">@{{message}}</div>',
        // data is technically a function, so Vue won't
        // complain, but we return the same object
        // reference for each component instance
        props: ['cardid'],

        data: {
            message: ''
        },

        mounted() {
            this.$parent.$on("card-details:message", message => {
                this.message = message;
            });
        },
    }),
```

add emit line in function:

```
    getCCDetails: function (id) {
        console.log(id)
        console.log('calling function')
        axios.get('/card/'.concat(id))
            .then(function (response) {
                this.message = JSON.stringify(response.data)
                this.$emit('card-details:message', this.message) // <--
            }.bind(this))
            .catch(function (error) {
                return this.message = 'Sorry there was an error'
            }.bind(this));

    }
```

And make `getCCDetails` function call only on `View Details` **button click**.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on phone sorry, try this:

- Set `:message="message"` in your card-details
- then in the  root Vue element, add a `:cardid="{{$cc->card_id}}"`, and don't forget `cardid` prop
- then implement `mounted` method in the root instance and call `getCCDetails(this.cardid)` from there.
- inside `getCCDetails` set `message` property

I hope this helps

Comment: I didn't want to run in mounted method because there can be anywhere from 1-10 credit cards on a customer's account and I don't want to make 10 requests before the page loads. I want the request to be made when they click the View Details button and the modal pops up. 

Also, for root Vue element are you saying to add a data array and return cardid="{{$cc->card_id}}" ?

Answer (score 0):

Modal is not for Ajax calls.
You must have Ajax calls from controllers.